# Add role to user with user mention

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I was trying to make a bot that is able to add a role to a user with a user mention. I also want to pass the role in the command.
So the syntax should be:
    `!addrole ROLENAME @user`
I tried this:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.utils import get

def read_token():
    with open("token.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        return lines[0].strip()

token = read_token()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def addrole(ctx, arg1, member: discord.Member):
    role = get(member.guild.roles, name={arg1})
    await member.add_roles(role)

bot.run(token)
```

but it doesn't work. I receive the error:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'`

Comment: Please post a [short, self-contained correct example](http://sscce.org/), detailing what you've tried, and why it isn't working.

Comment: I edited my post, please look again

Comment: To clarify, that's still not self-contained.  If I copy that into a python file, I will get errors because `bot` and `get` are not defined.  Also when posting errors, the _full_ traceback contains useful information.

Comment: Use `role:discord.Role` to convert the input into a role obj

Answer (score 1):

You're already using a [converter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#converters) for `member`, use one for `role` too:

```
from discord import Member, Role

@bot.command()
async def addrole(ctx, member: Member, *, role: Role):
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

The `, *,` allows you to supply role names that [have multiple words](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments).